# C# Windows Form Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am creating a Windows Form application and I want to have a base class that has basic functionality to manipulate input from a form and then inherit from that class to create 3 derived classes that are all slightly different.

Is it possible to have the base class not be an actual form, but instead just have an abstract class that is never instantiated, but has a couple functions that I wanted all the derived classes to have as well?

How can I do this in C#?

Thanks

Comment: it's possible but inconvenient to do because of VS designer

Comment: so what would you say is the best solution then?

Comment: First, you should ask yourself whether you actually need inheritance. It sounds like you need composition, not inheritance. In other words, why not put the functionality in a separate class, and give each form a property of that class type?

Comment: All the designer does is autogenerate the code in the `.designer.cs` file. There's nothing stopping you from writing such code manually in your subclasses, or from just subclassing a form class just like any other class (the designer-generated code in the parent class will still work if you don't override methods without calling the base implementation) and then instantiating it elsewhere without it being created using the UI designer.

Comment: @MattHintzke as Jason Watkins above advised - consider your functionality. Make user controls or utility classes that hold the functionality you want to share

Comment: That said, if all you want is to share "a couple of functions", and not a vast majority of the layout / behaviour code, use a class of utilities.

Comment: @millimoose ... except the part where you have to deal with the designer itself

Comment: @StenPetrov Why would the designer care that child classes of the form you're designing exist? Obviously the handcoded alterations in them won't be shown up but still.

Comment: @StenPetrov: The designer will work just fine with any class that inherits from Form.

Comment: So I shouldn't even use a designer for the base class then? Cause I dont ever need a view for the base class at all

Comment: @JasonWatkins I do think inheritance is best here because I want 3 unique classes I can implement. They are not compositions of each other

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `Custom User Control`

Comment: So you have some class `x`, and three classes, `a`, `b`, and `c` that need `x`. Now ask yourself, for each class "Is `a` and `x`, or does `a` *have* an `x`?" Everything you've described so far sounds like the latter, which means you should not use inheritance in this case.

Comment: @MattHintzke It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include more detail about what you are doing.